# AWS Cognito Change User Password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm following this tutorial https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/test-the-apis.html to create a react js app with AWS.

I followed every steps but now I'm facing a challenge, when i want to test my api with npx command with a user I created in the user pool, it needs to change his password.

```
npx aws-api-gateway-cli-test --username='mail@example.com' --password='password' --user-pool-id='user-pool-id' --app-client-id='app-client-id' --cognito-region='region' --identity-pool-id='identity-pool' --invoke-url='url' --api-gateway-region='region' --path-template='/notes' --method='POST' --body='{"content":"hello world","attachment":"hello.jpg"}'
npx: installed 106 in 7.229s
Authenticating with User Pool
Given user needs to set a new password
```

All ids are hidden in the command.

How can I do that ? I tried the change password command but it needs an access token and I don't know where to found it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: share your code where you made the login request.

Comment: Question edited ;)

Comment: You have created user pool and identity pool, but haven't logged in even once. You will have to login and change password once. I have only ever done this using AWS sdk so here's link to how you can do it with javascript https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-admin-created-user.html

Comment: Thx. How do I fills the parameters ?